# Can I create a SQlite data base for android reference to the ER diagram?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

Lot of tutorials shown are sqlite db created for one database table. I have a ER diagram with relationships where I have to create several tables. How can I do it and add the relationships ? I couldn;t find much when I searched for. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Creating a SQLite database with a relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859865/android-creating-a-sqlite-database-with-a-relationship)

Comment: @Sathya I didn't see it before. gratitude for sharing the link :) .